# convert Julian day number to date time format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in R

Tags: r, date, time, julian-date

How to convert Julian day number to date and time
if the origin is ("2000-01-01") and I have two Julian day numbers JDN (4822.178270,4822.17840)
what is the equivalent date time?
 the code is

```
JDN <- c(4822.178270,4822.17840)
temp<- as.Date(JDN +0.5, origin=as.Date("2000-01-01 00:00:00")) # that gave only date as "2013-03-15" "2013-03-15" without time.
```

# my result should be:

```
"2013-03-15 16:16:42" "2013-03-15 16:16:53"
```

Comment: No, it doesn't answer my question I need to find the time not only date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
as.POSIXct('2000-01-01')+((JDN+0.5)*24*60*60)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely surely about adding the 0.,5 here, but you had it in your original code so I left it in, otherwise the result is as mrhellman suggests.

Comment: your answer is correct and exactly as I wanted, and yes 0.5 is needed here. The answer of @mrhellmann also solved my problem. thanks for both of you and I am sorry I cannot click green tick for both, as the system allows for one only.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```r
JDN <- c(4822.178270,4822.17840)


origin <- lubridate::ymd_hms('2000-01-01 00:00:00')

origin + JDN * 3600*24
#> [1] "2013-03-15 04:16:42 UTC" "2013-03-15 04:16:53 UTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>